# How to implement callbacks using IntentService on Android?

Tags: android, service, aidl

If it must implement with AIDL?
And please kindly provide an example, thanks.

EDIT:
There are several solutions, Does anyone know which is better?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be looking for the `ResultReceiver` class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html).

You extend it, pass it along with the intent you invoke the `Service` with (it's parcelable), then when your task completes in the `Service`, you call the ResultReceiver's `onReceiveResult()` method with the results.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any alternative solution? I would like to know.

Comment: Well tell us if you've found any, because I couldn't find any better solutions. I don't really like it either, tho it does work.

Comment: I think the broadcast/receiver should work but have no idea if it is better or not.

Comment: I'm trying to use static Handler to send message back to main thread now. I think there must be mutiple solutions but which is better?

Comment: @shiami Did you ever have any luck with a static Handler in the main thread? This seems to result in null pointer exceptions for me if I don't have any Activities open.

Comment: @Scythe & to post owner, Could you find code snippet? Could you share it to us.. Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1):

checkout this post :[Using ResultReceiver in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510974/using-resultreceiver-in-android) , discussing the implementation of resutlreceiver.