# Using ResultReceiver in Android

Tags: android, service, callback, android-activity

Fundamentally, I would like to establish a callback to an Activity from an IntentService.  My question is very similar to the one answered here:

[Restful API service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197335/android-restful-api-service)

However, in the answer code, the activity code is seen as implementing a ResultReceiver.  Unless I'm missing something, ResultReceiver is actually a class, so it cannot perform this implementation.

So essentially, I'm asking what would be the correct way to wire up a ResultReceiver to that service.  I get confused with Handler and ResultReceiver concepts with respect to this.  Any working sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

1. You need to make custom resultreceiver class extended from
   ResultReceiver
2. then implements the resultreceiver interface in your activity
3. Pass custom resultreceiver object to intentService and in
   intentservice just fetch the receiver object and call
   receiver.send() function to send anything to the calling activity in
   Bundle object.

   here is customResultReceiver class :

   ```
    public class MyResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {

       private Receiver mReceiver;

       public MyResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
           super(handler);
           // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
       }

       public interface Receiver {
           public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData);

       }

       public void setReceiver(Receiver receiver) {
           mReceiver = receiver;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {

           if (mReceiver != null) {
               mReceiver.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
           }
       }

   }
   ```

implements the Myresultreceiver.receiver interface in you activity, create a class variable

```
Public MyResultReceiver mReceiver;
```

initialize this variable in onCreate:

```
mReceiver = new MyResultReceiver(new Handler());

mReceiver.setReceiver(this);
```

Pass this mReceiver to the intentService via:

```
intent.putExtra("receiverTag", mReceiver);
```

and fetch in IntentService like:

```
ResultReceiver rec = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiverTag");
```

and send anything to activity using rec as:

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
rec.send(0, b);
```

this will be received in onReceiveResult of the activity. You can view complete code at:[IntentService: Providing data back to Activity](http://sohailaziz05.blogspot.com/2012/05/intentservice-providing-data-back-to.html)

**Edit: You should call setReceiver(this) in onResume and setReceiver(null) in onPause() to avoid leaks.**

Comment: This is very useful for me. Thanks! Nice explaination!

Comment: this should be the correct answer, you need to use a handler to run the callback in the ui(main) thread. you cannot modify the user interface if you directly attach a ResultReceiver to your intent.

Comment: So does ResultReceiver always go hand-in-hand with an IntentService?  And is there a less complicated way to accomplish what the ResultReceiver does?  I mean, this architecture seems too convoluted and has too many circular dependencies.

Comment: But when `Activity` would be recreated you will never got your result back and moreover - leak the destroyed `Activity`.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky instead of this local broadcasat is better option.

Comment: @KemalDağ if you notice, handler is passed in mReceiver = new MyResultReceiver(new Handler()); so onReceiveResult will be called on handler's thread thats activity.

Comment: @SohailAziz , There is another approach by using sendBroadCast(intent) and a broadcast receiver in the activity. I used it but the performance was so bad and I got a lot of "doing much work on main thread exception". This approach I think is better. Can you explain the difference between them please. I used it with a Service not IntentService, service that sends location updates.

Comment: @user489775645 these are two totally different approaches, this one is based on handler pattern the other is receiver pattern. You can use local broadcast (available via support lib) sendLocalBroadcast(...), a much better option.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23059313/1428549) addresses the screen rotation/activity recreation scenario, by taking advantage of the fact that [ResultReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html) implements `Parcelable`. It can be saved during `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` and recreated from `Bundle savedInstanceState`.

Comment: Sohel, can i use a simple interface to recv data from Service to Activity ?

Comment: Since most services performing a background task will be involving a different thread it might be preferable to make sure that all access to `mReceiver ` is done with safe publishing of variables. In other words the variable should be either `volatile`, accessed via `synchronized` blocks or through a `AtomicReference`.

Comment: I'm confused by the usage of `setReceiver()`. I don't think it's necessary. I think you merely override `onReceiveResult()` and you're good to go. I think Eric Bowman's answer is simpler and more correct.

Comment: OK, I read your blog post. You're using the setReceiver() functionality to enable the receipt of results only when the Activity is visible (between onResume() and onPause()). You might also want to consider passing the ResultReceiver across instances of the Activity via [onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance())

Comment: I don't see how `setReceiver(null)` would prevent leaks.. `onReceiveResult` of superclass will still get called even if activity is destroyed. You just won't notice it because your interface will be removed but it will still get called.

Comment: If you save mReceiver as a instance variable in the Activity and you pass mReceiver to the IntentService, wouldn't you still have an implicit reference to the Activity from the IntentService through mReceiver?

Comment: A limitation here is that `ResultReceiver` cannot be cast to `MyResultReceiver` after de-parcelization correct?

Answer (score 23):

You override a method by subclassing. It doesn't have to be an interface to do that.

For example:

```
intent.putExtra(StockService.REQUEST_RECEIVER_EXTRA, new ResultReceiver(null) {
    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        if (resultCode == StockService.RESULT_ID_QUOTE) {
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is only have of the answer - can you show the corresponding IntentService side code that unmarshalls the ResultReceiver for the send() method?  That is causing me problems.

Comment: ... half (sic) ... I went back and studied the sample code from Google IO iosched and realized that I was making my "detattachable-resultreceiver" way too complicated.  As it turns out, on the server side, the extra is simply retrieved with the intent.getExtra("receiver-key") as one would expect.  No special magic.

Comment: It is quite simple and handy.

Comment: But the anonymous class holds an implicit reference to the enclosing class. It seems if this class is `Activity` we have the memory leakage during the configuration changes.

Answer (score 12):

I have created a simple example that demonstrates how to use `ResultReceiver`.

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("logName", "MAIN_ACTIVITY");
        serviceIntent.putExtra(MyService.BUNDLED_LISTENER, new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
            @Override
            protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
                super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);

                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    String val = resultData.getString("value");
                    Log.i(TAG, "++++++++++++RESULT_OK+++++++++++ [" + val + "]");
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "+++++++++++++RESULT_NOT_OK++++++++++++");
                }
            }
        });
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

**MyService**:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private final static String TAG = MyService.class.getSimpleName();
    public final static String BUNDLED_LISTENER = "listener";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        String logName = intent.getStringExtra("logName");
        ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(MyService.BUNDLED_LISTENER);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("value", "30");
        receiver.send(Activity.RESULT_OK, bundle);
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm looking at code I wrote two years ago, and completely forgot about ResultReceivers, thank you.

Answer (score -4):

for use Resulteceiver in android

1. Create SomeResultReceiver extends from resultReceiver
2. Create interface someReceiver with on method for example onReceivResult(int resultCode,Bundle resultData);

3.use someReceiver in someResultreceiver

4. create someService extends IntentService and use someresultReceiver.send() method for send result from service to someOne class (ex: MyActivity)
5. Implement somereceiver on Activity

6.instantiation someResultReceiver in MyActivity class and setreceiver

7. startService with Intent and putExtra someResultreceiver instanse

for more details ResultReceiver Class see [enter link description here](http://softvision.ir/Main/Article/12)

Comment: Link is dead. Please fix it or you will get more down votes.