# How to create a system service in Android with a custom permission?

Tags: android, android-service, android-framework

I want to create a system service. My requirements:

1. The service should be protected by permission. If possible, it should not be accessible to the user (accessible only inside Android system).
2. Service should be able to *return* some values. All the tutorials available on the internet give same example of setting int value.

I want to add this service to SystemServer.java so that it will be automatically started.
Some of solutions on stackoverflow suggest to create a system app/service, but I will be modifying Android source code to create a custom ROM.

Comment: what have you try so far?

Comment: I have followed this method: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android-Adding_SystemService

Answer (score 1):

First, i would suggest you to read the official documentation about [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html),

you can't protect service with permission, you can do some logic and protect your data with passwords with [MD5](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/MessageDigest.html) encryption, and with simple search i found for you nice question of [starting a service and returning data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135303/starting-a-service-and-returning-data)

EDIT:
Please note that it's uncommon for most application, [READ THIS BEFORE IMPLEMENTING](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#Permissions),
[EXAMPLE OF HOW TO USE CUSTOM PERMISSION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816623/how-to-use-custom-permissions-in-android)

Good luck

Comment: I might have stated my requirements incorrectly. I do not want protect the service itself, but the APIs provided by my service should be protected by permission. For example,  LocationManager's APIs are protected by 'ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION', 'ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'.

Comment: The link you have provided talks about defining custom permissions in Android app (in manifest file). How is it possible to define similar permission for a system service. Is there any manifest file associated with every system service?