# ResultReceiver doesn't survire to screen rotation

Tags: android, rest, service

I am implementing a REST client in Android.
I have seen an example of using a `Service` to perform the connection to the server and the `ResultReceiver` to be notified of the operation completion. I am calling the service from a fragment and, if I try to rotate the screen while the service is running, the getActivity() method in `ResultReceiver` returns null because probably that fragment is not in layout anymore.

The callback method in the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
    Response response = (Response) resultData
            .getSerializable(RestService.RESULT);
    if (resultCode == RestService.SUCCESS
            && response != null) {
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            recommendationResponse = response;
            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, new Bundle(),
                    Fragment.this);
        }

    }
}
```

The `getActivity()` returns null.
Is this normal? What approach could I use to allow notification even on screen rotation? Local Broadcast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a `BroadcastReceiver` registered using `LocalBroadcastManager` and it is working properly. It wasn't so simple. Does a better solution exist?

Answer (score 13):

No,

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

is not a solution.

To use ResultReceiver I:

- save it on orientation changes:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
      outState.putParcelable(Consts.RECEIVER, mReceiver);
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  }
  ```
- reset the receiver:

  ```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      if (savedInstanceState != null) {
          mReceiver = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(Consts.RECEIVER);
      }
      else {
          mReceiver = new MyResultReceiver(new Handler());
      }
      mReceiver.setReceiver(this);
  }
  ```

Here is my ResultReceiver class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.ResultReceiver;

public class MyResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
    private Receiver mReceiver;

    public MyResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    public void setReceiver(Receiver receiver) {
        mReceiver = receiver;
    }

    public interface Receiver {
        public void onReceiveResult(int command, Bundle resultData);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int command, Bundle resultData) {
        if (mReceiver != null) {
            mReceiver.onReceiveResult(command, resultData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I saw many other similar questions (with many upvotes) related to [ResultReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html), and any of them addressing successfully such a frequent scenario as activity recreation.

Comment: How do you avoid a ClassCastException in onCreateView() when calling getParcelable()? Doesn't getParcelable() return a ResultReceiver instance (not an instance of your subclass) because your subclass doesn't implement Parcelable.CREATOR?

Comment: @Alan With my testing, when you rotate the device, the above method works. However, if android shuts down the app in the background and you start it again, I get the ClassCastException in onCreateView(). I am not sure why but this is what I have found from my testing...

Comment: @MicroR I would guess this is because on rotation the Bundle does not get serialized to a Parcel, it stays in memory and so you get the original object back out. If the app is terminated (memory pressure) the Bundle is likely turned into a Parcel which is where you run into issues re-extracting the object because the Parcel will only return a base ResultReceiver. I still have not found a good solution.

Comment: @Alan Indeed! That makes sense. I opened a question here (http://stackoverflow.com/q/37439838/3075340) but is it possible to make the custom ResultReceiver implement parcelable or no..?

Answer (score 1):

I think I stumbled upon the same issue and resolved it by verifying for NULL in the onReceivedResult method of my ResultReceiver. The code posted here works on a worker fragment (fragment without UI and setRetainInstance(true) in onCreate)

```
protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            //Verify activity
            if(getActivity() != null){
                //Handle result
            }else{
                notificationPending = true;                 
            }
        }
```

The notificationPending flags helps the fragment hold the pending notification if the activity was not found (Activity is not available on fragment Detach).

When the fragment reattaches to the activity i perform this logic

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
        if(notificationPending){
            //Handle notification
            notificationPending = false;
        }
}
```

Hope it helps. You can ask for further details if you like. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this normal since the ResultReceiver might be "headless".

I tried saving the `ResultReceiver` at `onSaveInstanceState()`, but it didn't work, since updates, that happen while the receiving `Fragment` is destroyed, get lost, and the references to callbacks too.

An explanation and a possible solution can be found here: https://stanmots.blogspot.com/2016/10/androids-bad-company-intentservice.html

Another good read concerning this problem:
https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

My full solution how to use a `ResultReceiver` can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54334864/6747171

Answer (score 0):

in my case found another approach that works, maybe it will help someone too

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);//add this line

        
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

> The getActivity() returns null. Is this normal?

Android  Activities are recreated after device rotation.

After activity is recreated it does not holds old context.that's why your getting  `getActivity()` as null

> What approach could I use to allow notification even on screen
>   rotation? Local Broadcast?

If you dont want activity to recreated on screen rotation.mention following in manifest

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"    <<<<<<<<<
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And last You will have to override following in Activity.

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I would prefer to not set the screenOrientation on manifest because the layout is different in landscape mode so I cannot set that.