# Handling Pending Notifications with Result Receiver in Activity Service communication

Tags: android, callback, android-activity, android-service

Hi stackoverflow community. This is my first time asking a question so please forgive me if I have some errors in this post

I am trying to communicate an Activity with an Intent Service using the Result Receiver pattern explained in [this](http://itekblog.com/background-processing-with-intentservice-class/) post and discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510974/using-resultreceiver-in-android) in stackoverflow. Eveything is working OK in a sample app but I am not sure if this pattern is effective when Activity goes to background or gets killed by Android OS.

Basically, what I want to achieve is the following app behavior:

1. **Activity**: Starts IntentService to do some work. Passes ResultReceiver to receive progress updates
2. **IntentService**: Starts working, get Activity's ResultReceiver.
3. **IntentService**: Work is completed in 10%, notifies Activity by sending message to Result Receiver
4. **Activity**: Receives message in onReceiveResult
5. **IntentService**: Work is completed in 40%, notifies Activity by sending message to Result Receiver
6. **Activity**: Receives message in onReceiveResult
7. *At this point, user goes to another app. Activity goes to background dettaching first the Result Receiver. Android OS could also have destroyed this Activity because of an incomming call*
8. **Intent Service**: Work complete. Tries to notify Activity but no Result Receiver available. Saves message for later redelivery to Activity.
9. *At this point, user gets back to the app. Activity goes to foreground, attaches Result Receiver and gets pending message from Intent Service that notifies that work is done.*

So, my question is how to handle pending notifications of an IntentService to the Activity using the Result Receiver pattern?

Thank you very much.