# Store String from JSON, Use between Activities

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, textview

So im trying to parse JSON data from a API, Inside this JSONArray known as `systems`im provided with a `system_id` which is just a numerical string. I want to be able to save this string as a `systemID` variable, that can be used from inside the app in other activities.

Example, i want to parse specific data from that system, therefore my JSON url would have to look something like this to properly load this data.

```
JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url + systemID + "get_data" + "&key=" + apikey);
```

Here a example of how im getting the parsed System ID

```
try { JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
      String system_id = c.getString(TAG_SYSTEM_ID);
```

Now i just need to save this string.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty and fast written: static variables

Clean and better: Service (you have to start the service or it will be killed between unbinding of activity A and binding of activity B). The service class can store any session data you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to save your string. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you'd like to retrieve data in the form of JSON in the background. (Perhaps triggered by something the user does)

If this data needs to be available to all activities, you could let a Service do the network related stuff, and let activities bind to that service. Perhaps use a Receiver as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510974/using-resultreceiver-in-android), to let activities receive the data (Your system_id) as soon as it is available.