# Android: Why does ResultReceiver reference dissappear?

Tags: android, intentservice, android-intentservice

My android app has to communicate with a server. An activity thus creates an intent and starts an IntentService derivate.

Following some hints, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510974/using-resultreceiver-in-android), I extended ResultReceiver to handle the answers:
My activity implements the contained Receiver interface (thus implements onReceiveResult).

```
public class MyResultDistributor extends ResultReceiver {

// Class instances serves one purpose: To remember who gets the answer.
private Receiver mReceiver;

// Constructor: Apparently, the "handler" determines in which thread the result handling is done.
public MytResultDistributor(Handler handler) {
    super(handler);
}

// This is what the receiver of request answers has to implement.
public interface Receiver {
    public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData);
}

// Allows to clarify who is the receiver of request results.
public void setReceiver(Receiver receiver) {
    if (receiver != null) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), "Setting receiver.");
    } else {
        Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), "Unsetting receiver.");
    }
    this.mReceiver = receiver;
    if (this.mReceiver != null) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), "Set receiver.");
    } else {
        Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), "Unset receiver.");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
    // Anybody interested in the results? Well, then feel free to take them.
    Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), "Got result.");
    if (this.mReceiver != null) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), "Distributing result.");
        this.mReceiver.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
    } else {
        Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), "No receiver there.");
    }
}
```

The activity creates an instance of this, and sets itself as Receiver (excerpt):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyResultDistributor.Receiver {

public MyResultDistributor mDistributor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v(this.getClass().toString(), "onCreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDistributor = new MyResultDistributor(new Handler());
    mDistributor.setReceiver(this);

    (...)
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.v(this.getClass().toString(), "onPause");
    mDistributor.setReceiver(null);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.v(this.getClass().toString(), "onResume");
    mDistributor.setReceiver(this);
}

(...)
```

Now, when I run the activity, start my service, and it returns the result, it seems that `mReceiver` is null. But I cannot see where it gets set to null in the log !??

Log excerpt:

```
onCreate
Setting receiver.
Set receiver.
onResume
Setting receiver.
Set receiver.
Request Service was created.
Request Service has got an Intent.
Server answer: auth
Authenticated!
Got result.
No receiver there.
```

where the last 5 messages feature a different TID.

Why does the receiver appear set in one method and unset in the other one? Do I have a thread problem? Maybe done something wrong by using `new Handler()`?

Thank you for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I think I found my mistake:
I somehow passed the wrong receiver to my IntentService - so the instance I was watching was a different one.
Sorry for this unsolvable question... (since that code part was not displayed.).