# android NullPointerException for ResultReceiver in service

Tags: android, android-service

i'm try to create simple comunication with activity and service. then after get any help from documents i'm create this service to send data from activity to service and pass data from service to activity. but i get NullPointerException for ResultReceiver

My Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    resultReceiver = new MyResultReceiver(null);

    txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview);

    intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    intent.putExtra("receiver", resultReceiver);
    startService(intent);
}
```

My service (with error):

```
public class ToobaPayamakService extends Service{
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private MyTimerTask timerTask;
    private ResultReceiver resultReceiver;
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        resultReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("mLastID");
        timerTask = new MyTimerTask();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 1000, 1000);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        timer.cancel();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("end", "Timer Stopped....");
        resultReceiver.send(200, bundle);
    }
    class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask
    {
        public MyTimerTask() {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("start", "Timer Started....");
            resultReceiver.send(100, bundle);
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("s");
            resultReceiver.send(Integer.parseInt(dateFormat.format(System.currentTimeMillis())), null);
        }
    }
}
```

LogCat Result:

```
Unable to start service com.sample.myService@41283e90 with Intent { cmp=com.sample/.myService(has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.sample.myService@41283e90 with Intent { cmp=com.sample/.myService (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

error is for this line :

```
resultReceiver.send(100, bundle);
```

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510974/using-resultreceiver-in-android

Comment: Did you ever found what was the cause of the problem ?

Comment: Well if you want a working example you can look here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197335/restful-api-service)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is going to be the issue but:

```
intent.putExtra("receiver", resultReceiver);

--------

resultReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("mLastID");
```

Your identification strings do not match, that way will never work.

Hope it helps