# ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent) false when adding extras to the intent

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play-services, intentservice

I am currently working on adding the Google API Activity Recognition.

I succeeded in getting the Activities reported using a pending intent as shown in the sample at: http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html

Now, I would like a callback from the IntentService (fired by the pending intent). To do this I tried the solution found at: [Using ResultReceiver in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510974/using-resultreceiver-in-android)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, ActivityRecognitionIntentService.class);
intent.putExtra(ActivityRecognitionIntentService.REQUEST_RECEIVER_EXTRA, new ResultReceiver(null) {
    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        switch (resultCode) {
            case ActivityRecognitionIntentService.RESULT_ID_WITH_ACTIVITYRESULT:

                ActivityRecognitionResult result = resultData.getParcelable(ActivityRecognitionIntentService.RESULT_BUNDLE_ACTIVITYRESULT);
                DetectedActivity mostProbableActivity = result.getMostProbableActivity();

                observer.onNext(mostProbableActivity);

                // Get the confidence percentage for the most probable activity
                int confidence = mostProbableActivity.getConfidence();

                // Get the type of activity
                int activityType = mostProbableActivity.getType();

                Log.d(TAG, getNameFromType(activityType) + " confidence: " + confidence + " isMoving: " + isMoving(activityType));
                break;
            case ActivityRecognitionIntentService.RESULT_ID_NO_ACTIVITYRESULT:
                Log.e(TAG, "Nonfatal: no activity result");
                break;
            default:
                Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected resultCode: " + resultCode);
        }
    }
});
```

This unfortunately resulted in `ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)` always returning false.

```
/**
 * Called when a new activity detection update is available.
 */
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    // outputs "onHandleIntent false"
    Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent " + ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent));

}
```

Further testing showed that any extras passed to the intent caused the same problem, so for example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, ActivityRecognitionIntentService.class);
intent.putExtra("TEST", "TESTING");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ctx, 0, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(apiClient, 0, pendingIntent);
```

Makes yet again `ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)` return false. Removing the "TEST" extra, gives the Activity results as expected.

So finally my questions:

- Why does adding Extras to the intent make the intent unusable for Activity Recognition
- Is it possible to create callbacks in some other way. **Note:** this is for the purpose of a library project, so cannot use EventBus as I have no Activity/Fragment to receive posted events.

Comment: Any Solution? ?

Comment: @febaisi solved it in an alternative way, see the answer below

Comment: It's just a workaround. Right ? 
I think we should be able to somehow pass a serializable or parcelable object through the intent.

Comment: @febaisi That is true. I guess it may be by design to prevent tampering of the intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using a LocalBroadcastReceiver from within the IntentService, forwarding the results.

The implementation can be found in:  https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation

Answer (score 0):

This issue in the official codelab points the right solution: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/activity_transitionapi-codelab/issues/26

You need to specify the `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE` when creating the Pendint intent.

Note that once you subscribes to the detection, notifications can be received with a delay of minutes (i guess thats for battery optimization)