# startService() from a utill class and get result by overiding receiveResult

Tags: android

1) I have an utill class which I call from an Activity by passing the activity context.

2) Using the context I call a Service ( startService() ) from the utill class

3) I try receiving the result (by over-riding onReceiveResult() ) back in the original activity.

Is this approach correct? onReceiveResult() in the activity is not called !! Please advice

**Method of Utill Class**

```
public static void openExpenseDetailsScreen(Context context, String type, String entityID)
{

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,ZExpenseService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("entity",APIConstants.EXPENSE_DETAILS);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("entity_id",entityID);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(StringConstants.fromReportDetails,true);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

**Result is set from the Service Class**

```
 resultBundle.putSerializable("expense_details", getExpenseDetails(context,entity_id));

if (receiver != null)
        {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(errorMessage))
            {
                receiver.send(STATUS_FINISHED, resultBundle);
            }
            else
            {
                resultBundle.putString("errormessage", errorMessage);
                resultBundle.putInt("errorCode", errorCode);
                receiver.send(STATUS_ERROR, resultBundle);
            }
        }
```

**OnReceiveResult over-rided in the activity**

```
@Override
    public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData)
    {
        if(progressDialog.isShowing())
        {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        switch (resultCode)
        {
            case ZExpenseService.STATUS_FINISHED:
            {
                if (resultData.containsKey("expense_details"))
                {
                    // Handle result
                }
                break;
            }
            case ZExpenseService.STATUS_ERROR:
            {
                // Handle error
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you sending send() from service.post some code

Comment: @Godather i have added the codes for reference

Comment: How are you getting receiver reference in your Service?

Answer (score 2):

Send your `ResultReceiver` reference with Intent while starting Service then use same reference to send() [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510974/using-resultreceiver-in-android)