# best way to connect InputMethodService with a Service

Tags: android, service, ipc, android-input-method

i need some advice to connect a mine *custom Softkeyboard*, that's expanding the **InputMethodService**, with another **Service**; I need to call a method in my Softkeyboard from a generic Service.

The problem is that i can not extending the Binder class because the method **onBind() is defined final** in the AbstractInputMethodService...

which the best way to connect them? itent, AIDL, Messenger?

Comment: the problem is that I have to make these calls at every touch of the user, it means a lot of calls and I do not think it's the best solution, **what is the most efficient solution?**

Comment: Ops...sorry.  however as your suggestion I created a resultreceiver, I implemented it into my softkeyboard and from service can directly send my data to softkeyboard, something similar to this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/10266994/552771 and it's work well, I have not yet tried to implement AIDL, I will get significant benefits from using it? thx